# Win 7 was hanging on boot, after entering credentials

Tags: windows-7, boot, freeze

My computer hung up for the first time since I installed Win 7 on it.  I rebooted, and found that after entering credentials, it would either hang at the Windows Is Loading screen, or get past that and hang at a solid black screen.  I can boot into safe mode w/ network support just fine.
I rebooted again, and pressed F8 for the first time in my Win 7 life, and found the list a little different than in XP.  I used the Repair windows option and chose the startup repair.  It requested to restore to a previous version (not sure if it meant my whole OS or just the startup portion) so I allowed it.
Now when I enter my credentials and press enter/accept button, it hangs for about 5 minutes, then finally I get a Welcome screen.  I am waiting it out right now to see if I ever get any farther, but would like to know what you would have done to repair this problem, as I have never had my machines unbootable before.

FYI, I installed a new SSD about 2 months ago, but haven't had any problems until now, so kind of doubt this is the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would have done is to boot into safe mode and examine what programs, services, and shell-extensions are installed using a series of tools like [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902), [HijackThis](http://free.antivirus.com/hijackthis/), and [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) (and Services.msc).

That way, I would be able to disable everything suspicious and enable them one-by-one (frustratingly, rebooting each time) to narrow down exactly what is causing the problem.

Now that you have Windows running, you can try a program like [Soluto](http://www.soluto.com/) to find out what is causing the delay.

Comment: I used Soluto, and it is showing my boot time at 1:25, which is what it used to be, but now it is 5+ minutes.  Very strange--I wonder what point their timer starts.

Comment: Their timer starts when `services.exe` start the Soluto service. This means that something is blocking before that point. I would take a look at the drivers since that is almost certainly the cause. Check in Autoruns to see what drivers are installed and look for anything “hinky” (make sure to select the verify and hide options to reduce the clutter).